# ifdef HAVE_BYTESWAP_H not respected on MacOS?

Tags: c++, bazel

I am trying to compile [the following repo](https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/tree/master) but I am getting the following error:

```
external/com_github_libmpg123/src/libmpg123/swap_bytes_impl.h:20:10: fatal error: 'byteswap.h' file not found
```

If I go to [this file](https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/master/src/libmpg123/swap_bytes_impl.h), I see the following:

```
#ifdef HAVE_BYTESWAP_H
#include <byteswap.h>
#endif
```

Various related GitHub issues seem to indicate this header guard works ([example](https://gist.github.com/atr000/249599)). This seems to indicate that the import shouldn't happen unless `HAVE_BYTESWAP_H` is defined. I am currently trying to compile this on MacOS, which to my understanding, shouldn't have `byteswap.h` so I would imagine `HAVE_BYTESWAP_H` is not defined.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe provide your own implementation of byteswap.h?  See [this solution](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse/issues/6#issuecomment-363601678)

Comment: How are you compiling it? `./configure` then `make`?

Comment: FWIW when I want to compile `mpg123` on MacOS, I do it like this:  `autoreconf -iv ; do_configure --disable-modules --with-cpu=generic_fpu ; make install`

Comment: I am using Bazel to compile this, using the default BUILD file found in the repo.

Comment: https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/master/mpg123/config.h#L81

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @retired-ninja the problem that [`config.h`](https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/master/mpg123/config.h#L81) sets `#define HAVE_BYTESWAP_H 1`. `config.h` is used [here](https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/c397f3ee2733fa9befa610b12bf689a4937b5f55/BUILD.bazel#L23).

The BUILD file contains this section:

```
genrule(
    name = "configure_artifacts",
    srcs = [
        "configure.ac",
        "COPYING",
        "NEWS",
        "README",
        "AUTHORS",
        "ChangeLog",
    ] + glob([
        "**/*.am",
        "**/*.in",
    ]),
    outs = [
        "config.h",
        "Makefile",
    ],
    cmd = "autoreconf -i && ./configure " + " ".join(configure_opts) +
          " && cp src/config.h Makefile $(RULEDIR)",
)
```

You can try to replace the cmd argument in a way as @jeremy-friesner suggested:

```
autoreconf -iv ; do_configure --disable-modules --with-cpu=generic_fpu ; make install
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused because my understanding is that this `config.h` file is generated from this `config.ac` file, which itself already should check for the existence of `byteswap.h` (https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/master/configure.ac#L1297). This is specified in the `config.h` file (https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/master/mpg123/config.h#L1-L2) and in the BUILD file ( https://github.com/johnsheu/libmpg123/blob/master/BUILD.bazel#L169-L174). I'm curious why this wouldn't work as is?